# New to coding, having issues

Tags: python

```
Question = int(input("How old are you?"))
p = "Maybe"
if Question < 18: 
print(p) 
else: print("Wow! You're an adult!")
```

I was expecting this to run, but it says else is an invalid syntax. Im unable to figure out why

Comment: Is the indentation as shown the same as what you have in your IDE?

Comment: What's the *actual* error? What you posted would complain about indentation

Comment: indent line 4 by 4 space and after else add print in next line with 4 spaces from start of line

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask] for tips like how to write a good title. Also related: [Why post complete errors?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146/4518341)

Comment: I think in your *actual* code, you have both the `print` and `else` indented, which would cause `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` at `else`. This might help you: [I'm getting an IndentationError. How do I fix it?](//stackoverflow.com/q/45621722/4518341)

Comment: Use Warlus to rescue.     p = "Maybe"
    if (Question := int(input("How old are you?"))) <= 18: 
        print(p)          
    else:
        print("Wow! You're an adult!")

Answer (score 1):

You need to indent in Python at appropriate areas. What you are having is an `IndentationError`. Here are some [examples](https://www.askpython.com/python/python-indentation) of this.

```
Question = int(input("How old are you?"))
p = "Maybe"
if Question < 18: 
    print(p) 
else:
    print("Wow! You're an adult!")
```

The Python interpreter needs to understand if `print(p)` is in the outside or within the `if` statement block. To do this, proper indentation is required to indicate that.

**Also:** Make sure to keep a consistent way of indenting: 4 spaces or tabs. Do NOT mix both as this could cause an Indentation Error.

Answer (score 1):

Try with putting the print statement on a new line. Make sure to indent both print statements

```
Question = int(input("How old are you?"))
p = "Maybe"

if Question < 18: 
    print(p) 
else: 
    print("Wow! You're an adult!")
```

Answer (score 0):

based on what you have written, there is an indentation error after if statement.

```
if Question < 18:
  print(p)
```